# Should I send my mediocre test scores if it's not compulsory to do so?

Tags: application, funding

I want to apply for a scholarship, but my TOEFL score is 81 and I think it is not good enough. Sending language proficiency scores is not compulsory for scholarship application but it is encouraged. I am indecisive to send it. What is your idea?

Comment: Do you think you should have scored higher? If they interview you, will they think you have a bad or good English?

Comment: @Davidmh I know no thing about their expectations.

Comment: Unclear. Are you seeking for a piece of advice?

Answer (score 3):

In general, test scores are only used as the minimum requirement for the scholarship. High scores don't help but a score much below median would likely hurt you. If your application statement was well-written and your other materials (letters, grades) were good, I wouldn't worry. If the accompanying materials were weak, then you have much bigger things to worry about than your TOEFL.

Comment: The question was whether or not to send the test scores.  Does your answer address that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not satisfied, take the test again to improve your score.

If not, a score of 81 is good enough to get you into many schools. However, some schools require higher scores. Is there a minimum TOEFL score for the school you're applying to?

Comment: No, no minimum score is announced.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably winning the scholarship requires evidence of your fluency in English. If your test scores do not provide that evidence, you should *not* send them.  (But then the rest of your application still has to provide that evidence.)